# Datalist not retaining values on postback

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, datalist

I have a datalist control that is not retaining it values during postback when the control causing the postback is outside of the update panel that the Datalist resides in.  I have verified that viewstate is on for that usercontrol as well as all its parent controls.

My basic situation is that I have a Datalist that contains a user control on a page.  When the user selects several rows in a grid and presses a button, a datatable is filled on the backend and assigned to the Datalist which has its item template set to the UserControl.  On ItemDataBound I set specific properties in the control which customize the messages on that control to the specific item.  This is then popped up using the AJAX Control Toolkit Modal Popup[ Extender.  When the user presses Save the whole page posts back.  Data is collected from the user controls and saved to the DB and the popup disappears.  The issue I am currently having is that the DataList has 0 items when the save button is pressed instead of the appropriate number.  THis issue just started appearing after we upgraded from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug in the Infragistics Grid Control that was also located on that page.  As soon as we upgraded to the latest hotfix it solved the issue.  What a PITA to find though.